# How to use sqlite3 with node.js - what is smt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I want to be able to use sqlite 3 with node.js

I am using the code from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) and it works perfectly, However I do not really understand the code. For example:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

db.close();
```

- First off I dont understand what `stmt` is or what it does neither with `smt.finalize`
- What does the `(?)` do after `VALUES`
- Why use all of this smt stuff, why not just do this: (It works I tested it.)
  `db.run("CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
    db.run("INSERT INTO user VALUES (1,\"manu\")");`

I hope all my questions can be answered with a link to a good documentation!

Thank you!

Comment: For your first 3 questions look at prepared statements. Basically this is your answer there. As for the last, we can not tell you, what you did wrong, when you do not show the code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're new to both `sqlite3` and `nodejs`. The variable `stmt` is just a variable, you can change it to something more descriptive like `statement` or `query`.

The `(?)` string is more likely a placeholder for the variable `i`.
So you won't execute `stmt.run()` ten times. Basically it replace the `(?)` with the content inside `stmt.run()`, so it'll be like `stmt.run('INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (Ipsum 1)')`, and so on.

Using `stmt.run('SQL QUERY HERE')` is easy for one or couple operation. But if you need to iterate it, 10000 `stmt.run()` doesn't seem easy.

Docs: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API.

Comment: So if I wanted to add another column, `db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT, name TEXT)");` How would I go about  inserting a value into name?

Comment: Yes but how would I use `smt.run` to insert a value?

Comment: The variable `stmt` is just a placeholder so you don't call `db.run()` multiple times. You can use `stmt` if you want to, and if you want your application to scale.

I apologize, the `CREATE TABLE 'TEXT'` is for datatype.

You can insert value into your table with `db.run("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES ('Some info', 'Manu')")`.

Comment: Notice the single and double quote. It's to differentiate Node string, and SQLite3 query string. You can also do `db.run("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?, ?)", "Some info", "Manu")`.

Comment: If I do that I get an error: manu@hecht:~$ node web/node-sqltest.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table lorem has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied
    at Error (native)
manu@hecht:~$

Comment: It's because you're only passing 1 data to `INSERT INTO VALUES`. Your created table `lorem` has 2 field, info and name, in that order. So if you want to insert some data into it, you'll need like `INSERT INTO lorem VALUES ('Info here', 'Name here')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89261/discussion-between-manu-and-bentinata).